# Rails Fragment Caching updated_at Expiry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I'm testing out fragment caching in rails

In looking at this line in the rails guides:

"If the value of updated_at has changed, a new key will be generated. Then Rails will write a new cache to that key, and the old cache written to the old key will never be used again. This is called key-based expiration."

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching

I thought if I updated a resource using the rails console the cache for that resource would be expired and a new key would be generated, below is my code.

controller:

```
class WidgetsController < ApplicationController
  def show_widg
    @widget = Widget.last
  end
end
```

view:

```
<h1>Widget</h1>

  <% cache @widget do %>
    <%= @widget.name %>
    <br>
    <%= @widget.description %>
    <br>
    <br>
  <% end %>

<h2>I changed</h2>
```

The first time I run this code the entry is cached.

Then I enter the rails console and update the record manually, the record does have timestamps.

```
widg = Widget.last
widg.description = "asdsda"
widg.save!
```

`=> #<Widget id: 21, name: "testing again", description: "asdsda", created_at: "2018-08-25 12:01:21", updated_at: "2018-08-25 12:08:51">`

I then re-rendered the page thinking the cache would be expired, but I still see the previous entry.

Why is this? And how does the updated_at key expiration work? I am using Redis, would this not work the same for Redis as it does the Rails cache?

Comment: Assuming both your server and console processes are configured to point to the same shared (redis) cache, your described expectations seem to match the expected behaviour.

Comment: Try printing the cache key for debugging: `<%= @widget.cache_key %>`